# change URL using htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my url is `http://www.testsite.com/cities?city=hyderabad`

I want to change this to `http://www.testsite.com/hyderabad`

The code in my htaccess is

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /cities?city=$1 [L]`

Comment: Use a PHP Router. Thats better than .htaccess modified urls.
https://github.com/Teddy95/EasyRouter Thats a simple router

Comment: Read the first 2 lines of my question. You will understand @FDL

Comment: My url is getting redirected to http://www.www.testsite.com/ when I used the code you posted - @Daan

Comment: @user3883296 the first 2 lines are a statement, not a question.

Comment: Ok, how to change the first URL to the one in second URL? is my question

Comment: @user3883296 of course fill in your url.

Comment: the URL http://www.testsite.com/cities?city=hyderabad to http://www.testsite.com/hyderabad